# Is this a closure in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I defined event 'on' to my object ( newobj )

In the event on I need access to this member that I saved it before.

The issue that I don't get this value in on event. ( doesn't exist )

I thought that I need to add closure I tried to add it but it didn't work.

Could you advise me what is the problem  ?

Basic code

```
 create : function() {
    var self = this;
    var newObj = createNewObj()         
    newObj.on('selectData', function(evt){
                 ///some code on self
            });
```

With closure option 1

```
 create : function() {
    var self = this;
    var newObj = createNewObj() 
             return function(){     
    newObj.on('selectData', function(evt){

                 ///some code
            })};
```

With closure option 2

```
 create : function() {
    var self = this;
    var newObj = createNewObj() 
            newObj.on('selectData', function(evt){

            })
             return function(){
              // some code
};
```

Comment: For starters, `retrun function...` is a typo and a syntax error

Comment: sorry my mistake but it is not the issue

Comment: `return function(){...}` will not execute the function body unless the callee calls the return value.

Comment: could you give me an example ?

Comment: `return function(){...}` would need something like `x.create()();`

Comment: In both cases you are using closures. The event handler is a closure as well. If you use `self` it should all work fine (and assuming that's what you want to do). I cannot see anything wrong in the first code snippet you posted. Please provide more information (i.e. a more complete example), there is not really a lot we can work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function. This simple changed the `this` inside the function.

Try something like this:

```
create : function() {
  var self = this;
  var newObj = createNewObj() 
  return (function(){     
    newObj.on('selectData', function(evt){
             ///some code
    }.bind(newObj)
  )})();
};
```

Sometime in the future you will be able to use a lexicaly bound function. [See this article](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2012/04/09/javascript-fat-city/) :)

Comment: The first half should have been a comment.

Comment: FWIW, the self-invoking function expression is completely unnecessary here. Just writing `newObj.on('selectData', function(evt){...}.bind(newObj)` (i.e. only taking its body) has exactly the same effect.

Comment: You are right, I guess that this way the user who asked would understand it better and quicker. And s\he may had a more complex code originally where this snippet came from, so a copy-paste would be easier. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
create : function() {
  var self = this;
  var newObj = createNewObj() 
  return (function(){     
    newObj.on('selectData', function(evt){
             ///some code
    }
  )})();
};
```